# Using Jboss Arquillian with to ShrinkWrap jboss modules

Tags: java, testing, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I have a application which contains the following

- some server side logic which are bundled as a jboss module
- The EJB layer which is bundle into the EAR
- The RESTful layer which is bundled as a war which is in the EAR

Both the EJB and RESTful modules depends on the server side logic modules which are jboss modules. This server side logic has dependencies to other modules such as guava, hibernate, and some home grown modules as well.

Now i want to use Arquillian to write some tests to both EJB and REST layers. But to do that i cannot find any reference how i can include the jboss modules i have in the ShrinkWrap.

I tried searching for documentation but i couldn't find any reference. I only found ShrinkWrap Descriptor library for jboss modules, but not how to ShrinkWrap a complete jboss module with the required jar files.

It would be great if someone point me to a documentation or sample which shows how to ShrinkWrap a complete jboss module.

Comment: What are you using for your build tool?

Comment: I’m using maven

Comment: You mention using ShrinkWrap, but have you tried using Maven to do this? It could be done with various maven plugins. Are the modules part of the same maven project?

Comment: I was thinking that it would be easy to deploy the code changes with the ShrinkWrap approach since the Arquillian test base takes care of starting up the container for me. Otherwise i have to have a external container managed so that i can do deployments from maven and run unit tests with Arquillian.

Comment: You could use the `wildfly-maven-plugin` to configure the container, then have Arquillian start it and manage it.